# Fluent-ffmpeg: merging video and audio = wrong frames

Tags: javascript, angularjs, audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to merge a video (mp4) without audio stream with an audio file (mp3). I'm developing under nodewebkit a video software which means that I have to use ogg files, so when the user upload a video or a audio file it converts it in ogg whatever its format. Then when the user want to export its video I’m exporting frames from a canvas to PNG images. Once this is done I’m creating a video from the frames with a 30 fps with this following code:

```
var videoMaker = function () {

    console.log('videoMaker');

    var deffered = Q.defer();
    if (!FS.existsSync($rootScope.project.path + '/video')) {
        filestorageService.createFolder($rootScope.project.path + '/video');
    }
    audioMaker().then(function () {
        var commandVideo = new Ffmpeg({
            source: $rootScope.project.path + '/frames/%d.png'
        });
        commandVideo.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);
        commandVideo.addOptions(['-c:v libx264', '-r 30']).withFpsInput(30).format('mp4').on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('video', err);
        }).on('end', function () {
            console.log('video win');
            deffered.resolve();
        }).save($rootScope.project.path + '/video/rendu.mp4');
    });
    return deffered.promise;
};
```

Then i'm reconverting the audio wich has been uploaded by the user to mp3:

```
var audioMaker = function () {

    console.log('audioMaker');
    var deffered = Q.defer();
    if ($rootScope.project.settings.music.path !== '') {
        FS.writeFileSync($rootScope.project.path + '/music/finalMusic.mp3', null);
        var commandAudio = new Ffmpeg({
            source: $rootScope.project.settings.music.path
        });
        commandAudio.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);
        if ($rootScope.project.settings.music.fadeIn) {
            commandAudio.audioFilters('afade=t=in:ss=0:d=0.5');
        }
        console.log($rootScope.project.settings.music.fadeOut, $rootScope.project.settings.music.fadeIn);
        if ($rootScope.project.settings.music.fadeOut) {
            var time = sceneService.getTotalDuration() - 0.5;
            commandAudio.audioFilters('afade=t=out:st=' + time + ':d=0.5');
        }
        commandAudio.toFormat('mp3').on('end', function () {
            console.log('audio win');
            deffered.resolve();
        }).on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('audio', err);
        }).save($rootScope.project.path + '/music/finalMusic.mp3');
    } else {
        deffered.resolve();
    }
    return deffered.promise;
};
```

Until there everything is alright those files work well but when i do this:

```
var command = new Ffmpeg({
    source: $rootScope.project.path + '/video/rendu.mp4'
});
command.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);
console.log($rootScope.project.settings.music.path !== '');
if ($rootScope.project.settings.music.path !== '') {
    command.addInput($rootScope.project.path + '/music/finalMusic.mp3');
    command.addOptions(['-c:v copy', '-c:a copy']);
    if ($rootScope.project.settings.music.duration > sceneService.getTotalDuration()) {
        command.addOptions(['-shortest']);
    }
    command.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }).on('end', function () {
        console.log("win");
        //filestorageService.rmFolder($rootScope.project.path + '/frames');
    }).save($rootScope.project.path + '/video/rendu.mp4');
} else {
    filestorageService.rmFolder($rootScope.project.path + '/frames');
}
```

And my final file has the music and the right duration but the frames aren't right, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I finally find out how to fix this, the final video wasn't good because i was merging the video and the audio to the same video file which means that i was getting the data of the video via outsream while i was writing on the file. So in my program i created a temp folder which contains the video and the audio then i merge them to a new video file which is in an other final folder to finally delete the temp folder.